# Python exec() is not creating PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create an additional column on a spark dataframe.
The new column is made up of a concatenated columns list (col_list). All works ok up until when I actually execute the **exec()** line. The dataframe 'tb' is not getting created.

I am using exec() because the 'col_list' list is dynamically generated.

Not sure why the **exec()** is not able to create the new dataframe 'tb':

Here is the code:

```
exec("tb = table_df.withColumn('TestPrimaryKey',{0})".format(col_list))
```

Comment: Almost certainly, there is no good reason to use `exec`. I suspect the reason this isn't working is because you are trying to create this variable in a local scope. In any case, you must provide a [mcve] otherwise we can only speculate

Comment: I don't understand why not directly `tb = table_df.withColumn('TestPrimaryKey', col_list)`. And if you need this list as string then `tb = table_df.withColumn('TestPrimaryKey', str(col_list))` And if you have list of strings then ie. `"".join(col_list)`, `" ".join(col_list)`, `"-".join(col_list)` (etc.)  instead of `str(col_list)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want get a value inside a exec funtion, one way is using a list and append the result:

```
exec_return = []
exec("exec_return.append('value')")
value = exec_return[0]
```

In this case to get the tb value you can do this:

```
exec_return = []
exec("exec_return.append(table_df.withColumn('TestPrimaryKey',{0}))".format(col_list))
tb = exec_return[0]
```