# pyspark - execute dynamically framed action statement stored in string variable

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to execute union statement which is framed dynamically and stored in string variable. I framed the union statement, but struck with executing the statement. Does anyone know how to execute union statement stored in string variable? I'm using pyspark in databricks notebook.

```py
df1 = df.filter((col("vchDataSection") == "AccountMasterInfo") & (col("bActive") == 1)).withColumn("dfs", concat(lit(".union(df"), col("iRuleid"), lit(")")))

df2 = df1.agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(col("dfs")))).withColumnRenamed("concat_ws(, collect_list(dfs))", "AccInfoRules").withColumn("replacestr",lit(""))

df3 = df2.select(overlay("AccInfoRules","replacestr",1,7).alias("overlayed"))

var_a = df3.collect()

var_a = var_a[0].__getitem__('overlayed')

var_b = var_a.replace(')', '', 1)

print(var_b)

o/p: df533.union(df534).union(df535).union(df536)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is Python's `exec` function - as the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) say:

> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. object must be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed.

So you could execute a PySpark statement as string, like that:

```py
exec(var_b)
```

If you want to access the results of the union (which I assume you do) then you can append it to a Python list and simply access it with index:

```py
exec_return = []
exec(var_b)
output_df = exec_return[0]
```

Related thread - [Python exec() is not creating PySpark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506303/6870955)

Answer (score 0):

We need to append dataframe variable to store result of union statement.

df1 = df.filter((col("vchDataSection") == "AccountMasterInfo") & (col("bActive") == 1)).withColumn("dfs", concat(lit(".union(df"), col("iRuleid"), lit(")")))

df2 = df1.agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(col("dfs")))).withColumnRenamed("concat_ws(, collect_list(dfs))", "AccInfoRules").withColumn("replacestr",lit(""))

df3 = df2.select(overlay("AccInfoRules","replacestr",1,7).alias("overlayed"))

var_a = df3.collect()

var_a = var_a[0].**getitem**('overlayed')

var_b = "exclusionDF = " + AccInforules

exec(AccInforules)

once we append df variable (exclusionDF) to store union result and pass that to exec, it worked.

Comment: Formatting is not okay, usage of ``` maybe be required as well as grammar checks